# Partially signed bitcoin transactions

Tags: transactions, bip174-psbt

Is the `psbt` data format the only way to exchange information about the Bitcoin transaction or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PSBT format is especially used to exchange information about *incomplete* transactions, e.g. ones that are still being assembled or have only been signed by a subset of the transaction authors. There are a number of other exchange formats that were in use before PSBT was proposed, e.g. created by wallet services and hardware signing device manufacturers to communicate between their hardware devices and their software wallets.

Once a transaction is fully signed, the most common format you’d encounter would likely be the serialized transaction format used in recording transactions on the blockchain.